# How can I configure VSCode so most recently visited tabs stay visible

Tags: visual-studio-code

I often open many file tabs throughout the day but often bounce between the same 3 or 4 tabs for an extended period of time. I would like all of these tabs to be next to each other (and visible) in the tab toolbar. Currently when switching between the same few tabs, only one recently used one is visible while tabs I opened hours ago are adjacent to them (this causes me to use ctrl-P every-time to bring forward a recent tab)

Put another way, if a tab hasn't been used in a while, it shouldn't be visible next to tabs that are actively being used. Is there a way to configure this?

Comment: Is this new behaviour? I think I have the same issue since a recent update. No clue how to fix it

Answer (score -1):

Control+Shift+T if you have them closed will be able to reopen them, also you can drag and drop the tabs onto each other to have them lineup next to each other, they should automatically line up together under one window when opening files